# How do I open these wirecap nuts?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm changing a switch to a new one, when I opened up I noticed these wire cap nuts, I've never seen them before and my google didn't get me far.

How do I open these up?

[image][image]

Comment: Some you can't, just have to cut them off, many have a tiny release slot for a tiny tool to be poked into them, not clear in your pictures if there might be one on this version.

Comment: "hold the wire in place, steady light pull on the connector, and twist the connector back and forth."

Comment: It looks like a click-type jacket, if so, there would have a keyhole that can push open by a screwdriver.